# How to render images in SSRS from VARBINARY field in table

Tags: sql-server, image, t-sql, reporting-services, varbinary

I am trying to build a report that simply shows item information with an items' corresponding picture. The images have already been stored in my database as a varbinary data type. However, the images refuse to render in SSRS once the report is ran. How can I render the images properly?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/display-database-image-using-sql-server-2008-reporting-services.aspx)?

Comment: Derp. Thank you. Completely missed this.